# IP Anonymizing in Ruby on Rails (with IP Proxy)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, networking, proxy, ip, incognito-mode

How would one go about anonymizing one own's IP Address in Ruby via a proxy?

I am using an Amazon API gem but want to make sure the IP it is coming from is anonymous or from another IP that is not my real IP.

I have looked into this here:
https://github.com/ankane/ip_anonymizer
...but not sure if this will do what I want it to do.

Any feedback or suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: By IP (Internet Protocol, either IPv4 or IPv6) do you actually mean _IP address_? If you use an IP address that is not your IP address, that will break a lot of things. Most networking is request/response, with the response sent to the IP address on the request packet. If the IP address on the request packet is not yours, how would you expect to receive a response?

Comment: Good point. I meant using a proxy or 'fake' IP address to communicate with Amazon with. I edited my post. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: I would not consider that as anonymizing your address. It will still be a specific address back. You cannot just make up an address not related to your site, but you can use a proxy or NAT that give you a different address. That will work for a lot of things, but it requires maintaining a state, which really breaks the IP premise of end-to-end, where only the source and destination maintain the state. There are protocols and applications that get broken by that.